# Matching TinyMCE's pasted text sanitising

Tags: php, html, tinymce-4

I've had a good search for this, and perhaps it's not been asked before.

I'm using TinyMCE, then htmlspecialchar'ing the content, then it makes its way happily into my DB.  For brevity, I've not explained the full sanitization as it's of little relevance to the question.

Basically, I'm looking to apply some filters to the content when displaying from DB, but I've run into some issues when actually trying to match the string.

It seems like TinyMCE will escape some characters that are pasted in, but not all.   It seems like tags get converted to their html entities, but not special characters.

Is there a method of replicating this in php, rather than individually converting each character to match the content prior to sanitizing.

Here's an Example of the differences:

Example of original text

```
<iframe src="www.test.com"></iframe>
```

TinyMCE + HTML Special Chars turns this to

```
&amp;lt;iframe src=&quot;www.test.com&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/iframe&amp;gt;
```

HTML Special Chars on its own...

```
&lt;iframe src=&quot;www.test.com&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

HTML Special Chars twice

```
&amp;lt;iframe src=&amp;quot;www.test.com&amp;quot;&amp;gt;lt;/iframe&amp;gt;
```

---

Any ideas?  Or will I just have to escape the '<' and'>' tags on their own first?

I'd like to cover all bases, so it would be useful to replicate what TinyMCE does to pasted in text.

Comment: To add, the following works but seems to be very limited in scope and general methodology.

`$value = str_replace('<','&lt;',$value);`
`$value = str_replace('>','&gt;',$value);`